# Why $(x-5)^2-4$ can be factorised as $(x-5-2)(x-5+2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

I would like to understand why $(x-5)^2-4$ can be factorised as $(x-5-2)(x-5+2)$

I am particularly concerned with the term, $-4$.

Comment: Hint: $4=2^2$ .

Comment: An interesting example on that topic: how to factorize $x^4 + y^4$ without the use of complex numbers?

Comment: **convoluted hint**

Q: which number can be expressed as a square?

$\begin{array}{lll}
a)& 7\\
b)& e\\
c)& 4\\
d)& \pi\\
e)&\text{they all can}
\end{array}$

A: e. $7=\sqrt{7}^2,e=\sqrt{e}^2,4=2^2,\pi=\sqrt{\pi}^2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's Quite Simple..

You know, $a^2 - b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)$
Now, $(x-5)^2 - 4 = (x-5)^2-2^2$
Let $a=x-5 $ and $b=2$
So, $a^2-b^2 = (x-5)^2-2^2 = (a-b)(a+b)=(x-5-2)(x-5+2)$

Comment: I think this should be marked as the right answer based on your flawless explanation flow. Well done.

Answer (score 4):

Note that

> $$a^2-b^2=a^2-ab+ab-b^2=a(a-b)+b(a-b)=(a+b)(a-b)$$

Now put $a=(x-5)$ and $b=2$

$$(x-5)^2-4=(x-5)^2-2^2=((x-5)+2)((x-5)-2)=(x-5+2)(x-5-2)$$

Comment: This problem evaluates the students ábility to recognize a difference of squares as well as substitutions (also called closure: if $x$ is a number and $-5$ is a number, then $x-5$ is a number). +1 for "getting it".

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to look at it: Use the FOIL method on the right hand side.
$(x-5-2)(x-5+2)$ becomes $x^2-5x+2x-5x+25-10-2x+10-4$ 
Combine and cancel your like terms and you're left with $x^2-10x+25-4$, which of course can be rewritten as $(x-5)^2-4$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way without using fancy formulas
$$ (x-5)^2-4 $$
$$=x^2-5x-5x+25-4 $$
$$=x^2-10x+25-4 $$
$$=x^2-10x+21 $$
$$=(x-3)(x-7) $$
$$=(x-5+2)(x-5-2) $$

Comment: @Integrator, to someone that doesn't know, it can look fancy. I personally think it's stylish.